# GlutSolidSphere not solid

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

Hi my program is supposed to display a solid red colored sphere in the center of the screen, all i am getting is the boundary of the sphere :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
  glutInitWindowSize(800,600); 
  glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
  glutCreateWindow("Sphere");

  glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
  glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);
  glutMainLoop();

  return 0;
}


void renderScene() {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);

  glutSolidSphere(2.5, 50, 40);

  glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: could you include the source for `changeSize()` as well?

Comment: and perhaps a screenshot

Comment: The problem was indeed in the changesize function ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);` before your `glutSolidSphere(2.5, 50, 40);`

Comment: I'm positive that glutSolidSphere sets the polygon mode to solid on its own (while glutWireSphere uses the line mode automagically).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "boundary"?

Solid doesn't mean filled, it means the surface contains no openings. This is in contrast to `glutWireSphere`, which is just the wire frame.